# Probability of drawing cards in ascending order

Tags: probability

Given 200 cards where each card has a unique number from 1 to 200.

We randomly pick 30 cards (the order we pick them matters). What is the probability the unique numbers of the cards we pick are in ascending order?

Comment: There are $30!$ possible orders and all are equally likely....so $\frac 1{30!}$ (not a very large number).

Comment: @lulu: can you please explain why? Why we don't use the 200 anywhere?

Comment: The $200$ is a red herring.  When you say you randomly choose cards I interpret that to mean that every (ordered) set is equally likely.  That is to say $\{1,2,3\}$ is exactly as likely as $\{3,2,1\}$.

Comment: If you want to proceed by force:  the probability that the least card is in slot $1$ is $\frac 1{30}$.  The probability that the second smallest card is in slot $2$ (given that we know it isn't in slot $1$) is $\frac 1{29}$.  And so on.

Comment: @lulu: thank you very much of your help! {1,2,3} is not the same as {3,2,1} that's why i said order matters.

Comment: To expand on @lulu comment. Pick 30 cards from the 200. Now, keeping them in the same order, renumber them 1-30, based on how large the number is. What is the chance that the sequence is 1,2,...,30? Clearly, it's 1/30!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to elaborate on the comments, I'll give two different arguments.  The first, based purely on symmetry, and the second based on counting.

I. One way to get a uniform distribution is to select an unordered subset (with $30$ elements) and then choose a random permutation of it.  Here, we don't care which unordered subset we choose and we only want one of the $30!$ permutations.  As the permutations are equally probable, the answer is $ {\frac 1{30!}}$.

II. First we count the number of ordered subsets. As noted in the posted solution of @Hamid there are $$\frac {200!}{(200-30)!}$$

How many are in ascending order?  Well as any unordered subset can be put in ascending order in exactly one way there are $$\binom {200}{30}=\frac {200!}{(30!)\times (200-30)!}$$  Hence the probability is the ratio $$\frac {200!}{(30!)\times (200-30)!}\times \frac {(200-30)!}{200!}=\frac 1{30!}$$

Comment: could you explain the meaning of the 2nd term? The 1st term is the number of ways to select 30 cards out of 200. What is the 2nd term?

Comment: @Marco That's the (reciprocal of) the number of ordered subsets with $30$ elements.

Comment: ok so it is the probability of selecting an ordered set?

Comment: @Marco.  Not following.  You asked about the second term.  That's the reciprocal of the number of ordered sets.  It's not meant to be a probability.

Comment: @Marco  My second method starts with the remark that the desired probability is $\frac {\text {number of increasing subsets with 30 elements}}{\text {number of ordered subsets with 30 elements}}$.  That's all that's going on there.

Comment: yeah sorry I misunderstood one thing. It is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for the case when cards are required to be "consecutive", not in "ascending order"**

The total number of possibilities is 
$$
\frac{200!}{(200-30)!}
$$
The possible number of ordered choices is $200-30+1 = 171$$^*$. So the probability should be
$$
\frac{200-30+1}{\frac{200!}{(200-30)!}}
$$

$^*$ This comes from $1\to 30$, $2\to 31$, $\cdots$, $171\to200$.

**Example**: let it $4$ and $2$, your choices are $12,13,14,21,23,24,31,32, 34, 41,42,43$. What you are looking for are $12,23,34$. So the probability is
$$
\frac{4-1+2}{\frac{4!}{(4-2)!}}=\frac{3}{12}
$$

Comment: The OP specified "ascending order" not "consecutive".

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks for the comment, I will just leave it and make a note about this.

Comment: So you are right, it is $\frac{1}{30!}$