# probability of drawing 4 cards in ascending order from a deck containing 97 cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am analyzing solution to the below problem (variation of the [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731077/probability-of-drawing-cards-in-ascending-order))

> 4 cards are drawn from the 97  card deck. What is probability that
>   they are drawn in ascending order?

The proposed solution says that the probability is 
$$1 * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4!} $$
regardless of number of cards in the stack.

I don't understand the solution. 

 **How the cases where the same cards (AA, KK etc) are drawn are reflected in the calculation? 

Why the number of cards in the deck doesn't play a role. Intuitively more cards in the deck would translate in more combinations.**

Can anybody explain please?

Comment: This is not a deck of standard playing cards. It's a pile of sequentially numbered cards. Also, the four cards are drawn without replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each card has a unique value.

If you know the values of the four cards, there are $4!$ equally probably orderings of which $1$ is in ascending order

Overall there are $\displaystyle 97\times 96 \times 95 \times 94= 4!{97 \choose 4}$ equally probable ways you can choose the four cards, of which $\displaystyle {97 \choose 4}$ are in ascending order

So the probability the four cards are in ascending order is $\dfrac1{4!}$. The $97$ does not affect this